# Implicit argument not always used depending on how it's written

Tags: agda

I have a function with the following type signature:

```
loop : ∀ {x y z} → .⦃ _ : Rights y ⦄ → DRuby (⟨ x , y ⟩ , ⟨ y , z ⟩) → DRuby (x , z)
```

where the `⟨_⟩` notation is for constructing rose trees and `Rights y` is a data structure that witnesses that a certain property holds for a rose tree.

I often have to write `.⦃ _ : Rights y ⦄` and `.⦃ _ : Lefts y ⦄`, sometimes multiple of these in a single type signature, and it starts to get a bit long, so to shorten things I came up with

```
infixr 5 R_⇒_
R_⇒_ : DShp → Set → Set
R x ⇒ y = .⦃ _ : Rights x ⦄ → y
```

and then I can write the above type signature as

```
loop : ∀ {x y z} → R y ⇒ DRuby (⟨ x , y ⟩ , ⟨ y , z ⟩) → DRuby (x , z)
```

However, in some cases the original version with `.⦃ _ : Rights y ⦄` works but the version with `R y ⇒` fails to typecheck - I get errors about failing to solve constraints/resolve instance arguments. Furthermore, I am unable to pattern match on the instance argument:

```
loop {x} {y} {z} ⦃ p ⦄ q = ?
```

gives the error

```
Unexpected implicit argument
when checking that the clause
loop {x} {y} {z} ⦃ p ⦄ q = ?
has type
{x : Rose (Type × Dir)} {y : _B_1266 x} {z : Rose (Type × Dir)} →
R x ⇒ DRuby (RS.⟨ _r_1261 ⟩ (x , y) , RS.⟨ _r_1269 ⟩ (y , z)) →
DRuby (x , z)
```

But there are a number of other functions where it typechecks just fine with `R y ⇒` (and doesn't typecheck if I remove it, so it is being used).

I suppose my question is twofold:

1. Is it expected behaviour that when defining a function like `R_⇒_` I can't pattern match on the contents, and that sometimes the contents aren't found during instance search?
2. Is there a way to make a function/synonym/macro like `R_⇒_` that works properly? For example, something like a C macro that is just a textual substitution?

Comment: Does Agda parse `loop : ∀ {x y z} → R y ⇒ DRuby (⟨ x , y ⟩ , ⟨ y , z ⟩) → DRuby (x , z)` as `loop : ∀ {x y z} → R y ⇒ (DRuby (⟨ x , y ⟩ , ⟨ y , z ⟩) → DRuby (x , z))` or as `loop : ∀ {x y z} → (R y ⇒ DRuby (⟨ x , y ⟩ , ⟨ y , z ⟩)) → DRuby (x , z)`?

Comment: @Jesper You're right, wrapping it in parentheses works! And it looks like precedence for `→` is the lowest possible (handled directly by the parser) so the parentheses are always needed. If you add that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Jesper for solving the problem for me: `→` has the lowest precedence of all operators as it is handled directly by the parser rather than parsed as a symbol and resolved into an operator later. As a result, any piece of code like `a * b → c`, where `*` is a binary operation, will be parsed as `(a * b) → c`, no matter what precedence you give `*`. In this case it parses `R x ⇒ y → z` as `(R x ⇒ y) → z`, which means that `Rights x` can't be used except in `y`. The solution is to add parentheses: `R x ⇒ (y → z)`.